# Entity Framework avoid subquery created by GroupBy

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, timescaledb

The following LINQ code

```cs
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Measure), "x");

var args = new List<SqlExpression>
{
    new SqlConstantExpression(Expression.Constant(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)), new TimeSpanTypeMapping("interval")),
    new SqlFragmentExpression("time")
};

var timeBucket = new SqlFunctionExpression(
    "time_bucket_gapfill";
    args,
    false,
    args.Select(_ => false),
    typeof(DateTimeOffset),
    new DateTimeOffsetTypeMapping("timestamp with time zone")
);

var keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Measure, DateTimeOffset>>(timeBucket, param);

_dbContext
    .Measures
    .Where(x => x.Time > start && x.Time < end)
    .GroupBy(
        KeySelector,
        (timeSample, measures) =>
            new KeyValuePair<DateTimeOffset, double>(
                timeSample,
                measures.Average(x => x.Value)
            )
    ).Take(10);
```

generates the following SQL:

```sql
-- @__p_0='10'
SELECT t0."Key", avg(t0.value::double precision)
FROM (
    SELECT t.value, time_bucket_gapfill('00:15:00', time) AS "Key"
    FROM measures AS t
    WHERE t.time > TIMESTAMPTZ '2010-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' AND t.time < TIMESTAMPTZ '2010-02-01 00:00:00+00:00'
) AS t0
GROUP BY t0."Key"
LIMIT @__p_0
EOF
```

The problem is that the function `time_bucket_gapfill` must be placed in the same (sub)query of the GROUP BY and WHERE clause with time bounds. So the above generated query does not work: what I need is

```sql
-- @__p_0='10'
SELECT time_bucket_gapfill('00:15:00', time) AS "Key", avg(t.value::double precision)
FROM measures AS t
WHERE t.time > TIMESTAMPTZ '2010-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' AND t.time < TIMESTAMPTZ '2010-02-01 00:00:00+00:00'
GROUP BY "Key"
LIMIT @__p_0
EOF
```

I couldn't find a way to achieve this with EF, a part from using `FromSql` on the DB set, which I wouldn't like to do.

I though of creating a `SelectExpression` by hand, but there is no documentation on this field.

I use Entity Framework Core 7.0.3 with PostgreSQL.

**UPDATE**

For having some context I add some information about timescale: it does not influence the question, but motivates why the two above query are different.

`measures` is a Timescale [hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/hypertables/about-hypertables/) (i.e. I called `SELECT create_hypertable('measures', 'time');`).

The SQL function `time_bucket` returns the [time bucket](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/time-buckets/) of the record: it takes the `time` column and rounds it to the nearest time sample (dictated by the given interval).

In addition, the SQL function [`time_bucket_gapfill`](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/gapfilling/time_bucket_gapfill/) adds an empty record for each time bucket for which there is no record. This function, to work correctly, must be called in the SELECT of the same (sub)query in which there are the GROUP BY and the WHERE clause restricting the time: only in this way it can know the interval in which to fill the gaps.

**MWE**

```cs
public class Measure
{
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    protected BaseMeasure(DateTimeOffset time, double value)
    { 
        Time= time;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class MeasureConfiguration
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Measure> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("measures");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Time);

        builder.Property(x => x.Time)
            .HasColumnName("time");

        builder.Property(x => x.Value)
            .HasColumnName("value");
    }
}

public sealed class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Measure> Measures { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MeasureConfiguration());
    }
}
```

There is no need of data into the table: the gapfill will return empty time buckets if working correctly.

After running the EF migration, execute the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT create_hypertable('measures', 'time');
```

Then the query generated by EF (the first above) will return nothing; instead the second query will return a record every 15 minutes from 2010-01-01 to 2010-02-01, where the value column is null.

Comment: Use ToDictionary : _dbContext
    .Measures
    .Where(x => x.Time > start && x.Time < end)
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .GroupBy(KeySelector)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.key, y => y.Avg())
    ).Take(10);

Comment: But doesn't ToDictionary execute the query? So the following Take would be in the wrong place, moreover I would like to get an IQueryable, not an IEnumerable (for example to paginate or aggregate the results)

Comment: The two queries (one of which you are saying is "does not work") look equivalent to me. Why do you think its a problem?

Comment: @topsail they seem equivalent, but they are not: the timescale function `time_bucket_gapfill` doesn't work properly in the first query: it groups the measures in time buckets, but doens't fill the time gaps, whilst with the second query it works. It is because of the timescale function implementation: removing that call the two queries are equivalent. Nonetheless I would expect in general terms EF to generate the second query and not the first, because that subquery is pointless: all it does is adding unuseful overhead.

Comment: I think you will need to provide more details. What is timescale doing that makes these two queries different? Provide sample data. Create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well to be honest I don't see how you can expect EF to be able to handle a function that actually returns data when empty tables are queried. If there is a case where you should use FromSql, or more generally raw sql rather than EF generated queries, this is it. As I said, for any kind of normal sql, the query generated is perfectly fine. That's probably as much as you can ask of EF here.

Comment: EF correctly handles the function, the problem is the superfluous subquery. Yes with FromSql it correctly works, but I lose the ability to add where clauses and aggregations via linq: I had to pass them to the function which calls FromSql and I have to manually translate them in SQL, making so EF pointless. I am sure there a way to avoid this: debugging the code I discovered that EF translates the IQueryable into two SelecetExpressions, one child of the other; what I would need is to transform that in a single SelectExpression with the GropuBy of the parent, the Filters of the child, ...